# Sum up Specific columns in a Dataframe from sqlite

Tags: python-3.x, dataframe

im relatively new to Dataframes in Python and running into an Issue I cant find.

im having a Dataframe with the following column layout

```py
print(list(df.columns.values)) returns:

['iccid', 'system', 'last_updated', '01.01', '02.01', '03.01', '04.01', '05.01', '12.01', '18.01', '19.01', '20.01', '21.01', '22.01', '23.01', '24.01', '25.01', '26.01', '27.01', '28.01', '29.01', '30.01', '31.01']
```

normally i should have a column for each day in a specific month. in the example above its December 2022. Sometimes Days are missing which isnt an issue.

i tried to first get all given columns that are relevant by filtering them:

```
# Filter out the columns that are not related to the data
data_columns = [col for col in df.columns if '.' in col]
```

Now comes the issue:

Sometimes the column "system" could also be empty so i need to put the iccid inside the system value:

```
df.loc[df['system'] == 'Nicht benannt!', 'system'] = df.loc[df['system'] == 'Nicht benannt!', 'iccid'].iloc[0]
df.loc[df['system'] == '', 'system'] = df.loc[df['system'] == '', 'iccid'].iloc
grouped = df.groupby('system').sum(numeric_only=False)
```

then i tried to create that needed 'data_usage' column.

```
grouped['data_usage'] = grouped[data_columns[-1]]
grouped.reset_index(inplace=True)
```

By that line i should normally only get the result of the last column in the dataframe (which was a workaround that also didnt work as expected)

Now what im trying to get is the sum of all columns which contain a date in their name and add this sum to a new column named data_usage.

the issue im having here is im getting results for systems which dont have an initial system value which have a data_usage of 120000 (which is just value that represents the megabytes used) and if i check the sqlite file the system in total only used 9000 mb in that particular month.

For Example:

im having this column in the sqlite file:

| iccid | system | last_updated | 06.02 | 08.02 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 8931080320014183316 | Nicht benannt! | 2023-02-06 | 1196 | 1391 |

and in the dataframe i get the following result:

`8931080320014183316       48129.0`

I cant find the issue and would be very happy if someone can point me into the right direction.

Here are some example data as requested:

| iccid | system | last_updated | 01.12 | 02.12 | 03.12 | 04.12 | 05.12 | 06.12 | 07.12 | 08.12 | 09.12 | 10.12 | 11.12 | 12.12 | 13.12 | 14.12 | 15.12 | 16.12 | 17.12 | 18.12 | 19.12 | 20.12 | 21.12 | 22.12 | 23.12 | 28.12 | 29.12 | 30.12 | 31.12 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 8945020184547971966 | U-O-51 | 2022-12-01 | 2 | 32 | 179 | 208 | 320 | 509 | 567 | 642 | 675 | 863 | 1033 | 1055 | 1174 | 2226 | 2277 | 2320 | 2466 | 2647 | 2679 | 2713 | 2759 | 2790 | 2819 | 2997 | 3023 | 3058 | 3088 |
| 8945020855461807911 | L-O-382 | 2022-12-01 | 1 | 26 | 54 | 250 | 385 | 416 | 456 | 481 | 506 | 529 | 679 | 772 | 802 | 832 | 858 | 915 | 940 | 1019 | 1117 | 1141 | 1169 | 1193 | 1217 | 1419 | 1439 | 1461 | 1483 |
| 8945020855461809750 | C-O-27 | 2022-12-01 | 1 | 123 | 158 | 189 | 225 | 251 | 456 | 489 | 768 | 800 | 800 | 800 | 800 | 800 | 800 | 2362 | 2386 | 2847 | 2925 | 2960 | 2997 | 3089 | 3116 | 3448 | 3469 | 3543 | 3586 |
| 8931080019070958450 | L-O-123 | 2022-12-02 | 0 | 21 | 76 | 313 | 479 | 594 | 700 | 810 | 874 | 1181 | 1955 | 2447 | 2527 | 2640 | 2897 | 3008 | 3215 | 3412 | 3554 | 3639 | 3698 | 3782 | 3850 | 4741 | 4825 | 4925 | 5087 |
| 8931080453114183282 | Nicht benannt! | 2022-12-02 | 0 | 6 | 45 | 81 | 95 | 98 | 101 | 102 | 102 | 102 | 102 | 102 | 102 | 103 | 121 | 121 | 121 | 121 | 149 | 164 | 193 | 194 | 194 | 194 | 194 | 194 | 194 |
| 8931080894314183290 | C-O-16 N | 2022-12-02 | 0 | 43 | 145 | 252 | 386 | 452 | 532 | 862 | 938 | 1201 | 1552 | 1713 | 1802 | 1855 | 2822 | 3113 | 3185 | 3472 | 3527 | 3745 | 3805 | 3880 | 3938 | 4221 | 4265 | 4310 | 4373 |
| 8931080465814183308 | L-O-83 | 2022-12-02 | 0 | 61 | 169 | 275 | 333 | 399 | 468 | 858 | 1094 | 1239 | 1605 | 1700 | 1928 | 2029 | 3031 | 4186 | 4333 | 4365 | 4628 | 4782 | 4842 | 4975 | 5265 | 5954 | 5954 | 5954 | 5954 |
| 8931082343214183316 | Nicht benannt! | 2022-12-02 | 0 | 52 | 182 | 506 | 602 | 719 | 948 | 1129 | 1314 | 1646 | 1912 | 1912 | 1912 | 1912 | 2791 | 3797 | 3944 | 4339 | 4510 | 4772 | 4832 | 5613 | 5688 | 6151 | 6482 | 6620 | 6848 |
| 8931087891314183324 | L-O-119 | 2022-12-02 | 0 | 19 | 114 | 239 | 453 | 573 | 685 | 800 | 1247 | 1341 | 1341 | 1341 | 1341 | 1341 | 1341 | 1341 | 1341 | 1341 | 1341 | 1341 | 1341 | 1341 | 1423 | 2722 | 3563 | 4132 | 4385 |

Comment: Set breakpoints and segment your code. Try not to let the one-liners get too long. I'm definitely an offender on that one. Also look at using chaining to keep your code clean. if you update your code to include some sample data from the beginning, then I can help you out.

Comment: @georgwalker45 I added some sample data just to show the construction of the sqlite database